# Servlet is not updated after modifing code (Netbeans/Tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans, servlet-3.0

I'm working on a Java EE application and I have faced the following problem:

When I modify the code of the servlet and re-run it's the old version that is displayed. I have cleared the logs of Tomcat and restarted it but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Souns like a compilation problem.

Comment: I guess it is.. But I don't know  if the problem is related to Netbeans or Tomcat!

Comment: If you're using Maven: try maven -clean.

Comment: @UmeiEl follow the steps
- undeploy project 
- clean the project
- redoply

Answer (score 0):

yes some times it will happens like this. just do one thing. delete the tomcat and re configure it .it will work, this is the problem with IDE only.